# Regex: The word must have an apostrophe at the beginning and at the end ("word")

Tags: javascript, regex

I currently have the following program that uses a regular expression:

```
const regex = /[\s]|('[^']')|[\w-]+|[']/gm;
```

When running:

```
console.log("'one 'two' three'".match(regex) || []);
```

I get:

```
[
    "'",
    "one",
    " ",
    "'",
    "two",
    "'",
    " ",
    "three",
    "'"
]
```

I need to update the regular expression in a way that I can get at the end:

```
[
    "'",
    "one",
    " ",
    "'two'",
    " ",
    "three",
    "'"
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed `+` inside your quoted pattern.

```
\s|('[\w-]+')|[\w-]+|'
```

```js
console.log("'one 'two' three'".match(/\s|('[\w-]+')|[\w-]+|'/gm) || []);
// Array(7) [ "'", "one", " ", "'two'", " ", "three", "'" ]
```

Also I've changed it to match only word symbols and minuses (by analogy with next pattern), to exclude matching of `'one '`.

If matching of phrases in quotes (like `'abc abc'`) is expected you could you could use `\s|('(?=[\S])[^']+?(?<=[\S])')|[\w-]+|'`

EDIT: according to corrected input by OP, to allow words containing `'`, like `that's`:

```
\s|((?<=[\s|^])'[\w-][\w'-]*[\w-]'(?=\s|$))|[\w-][\w'-]*[\w-]|'|\w
```

Comment: Excellent, thanks a lot! I've spent about 2 hours to understand how it should work....
I "really" love these regex expressions)

Comment: @RomanSlisarenko, sites like regex101.com provide nice support for writing regexes. Try it out.

Comment: Could you tell me please what to do in those cases when we have a word like: that's ?. Expected result of execution: console.log(“that’s”.match(regex) || []); should be: [“that’s”]

Comment: Try `\s|('[\w'-]+')|[\w'-]+|'`

Comment: It works for thats but not suitable for previous logic...
Expected result of execution:
console.log("that's 'one 'two' three'".match(regex) || []);
should be: [“that’s”, " ", "one", " ", "'two'", " ", "three"]

Comment: Try. `\s|((?<=[\s|^])'[\w-][\w'-]*[\w-]'(?=\s|$))|[\w-][\w'-]*[\w-]|'|\w`. But at this point if this doesn't help, I recommend you generate bigger list of possible incomes and add int to your question, so other could easier see it.

Comment: I'm so sorry if it was difficult to understand me, but you managed it. The last expression covers even more cases - great!

Comment: The problem was found later, you may need it in the future:
Regex ?<= not supported Safari iOS: https://caniuse.com/js-regexp-lookbehind

Comment: @RomanSlisarenko, I don't think it is possible to match what and how you what without lookarounds. But you could create new question, specify that it should work without lookarounds and provide extensive example of input and output, maybe you'll be suggested with some good ideas.